# Does Graph And Relation Mean The Same Thing?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, definition, relations

I understand that every function is equal to some graph, while not every graph corresponds to a function; so that sets aside the difference between functions and graphs. However, I understand that any relation can be represented with a graph, and every graph coresponds to some relation. Therefore, are the set-theoretic structures of "relations" and "graphs" exactly identical? Are they just different names of the same set?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by graph? Is it a combinatorial graph or a subset of the cartesian product of two sets? I think the word is used with several meanings in math.

Comment: A relation is a function precisely if it is a graph (if $xRy$ and $xRy'$ then $y=y'$). There are many more relations than there are functions/graphs

Comment: @Keen-ameteur well the book I'm using defines a graph to be a set of ordered pairs. However, I don't see how it is distinguished from the notion of a relation. It says that a function is a "rule" that determines the ordered pairs of a graph; and that to avoid introducing a new undefined concept of a "rule" the author defines a function to be equal to precisely it's graph. What about relations?

Comment: I know of combinatorial graphs and graphs of functions. I think you should your definition of a graph, then. Because depending on your working definition, it might be equivalent to a relation.

Comment: I meant to say you should give your definition.